# Displaying an aria-hidden element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap alert box

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <div id="errorText">
        ERROR!
    </div>
</div>
```

To display the alert I'm using a button

```
<button type="button" onClick="showAlert()" >Show Alert</button>
```

Which executes the following function to display the alert.

```
function showAlert(){
    $('.alert-danger').show();
}
```

After I close the alert by clicking on the X, clicking on the "Show Alert" button doesn't display the alert anymore. What do I need to do to set aria-hidden to false?

Here is a jsFiddle for it, but for some reason it doesn't even display the initial alert. 
https://jsfiddle.net/3ytoz79p/

Comment: Have a look at my update below, if you dont mind the button also hiding the alert, `.toggle()` would be shorter than my original answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-hidden="true"` is actually not the culprit here. The issue is actully that `data-dismiss="alert"` does not *hide* the alert, it *removes it from the DOM*. You can see this by inspecting the DOM after you click the dismiss button.

To do what you want, you could change your code to this:

```js
$('.close-alert').click(function(event){
  $('.my-alert').hide();
});

$('.show-alert').click(function(event){
  $('.my-alert').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-alert alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close close-alert"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <div id="errorText">
    ERROR!
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="show-alert" >Show Alert</button>
```

You could also make it shorter with:

```js
$('.toggle-alert').click(function(){
  $('.my-alert').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-alert alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close toggle-alert"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <div id="errorText">
    ERROR!
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="toggle-alert" >Toggle Alert</button>
```